# Чем заменить родственный селектор css

Tags: css

В первом варианте без оберток табы отрабатывают за счет вот этих стилей:

```
#tab_1:checked ~ #txt_1,
#tab_2:checked ~ #txt_2,
#tab_3:checked ~ #txt_3,
#tab_4:checked ~ #txt_4 {
  display: block; 
}
```

Вопрос: как добраться с помощью стилей к текстовым блокам во втором случае, если и переключатели, и текстовые блоки находятся в обертках, чтобы они отображались с переключением табов?
Не могу найти какие стили нужно применить.
Родственный селектор (тильда) `~` дает возможность доступа только к элементам с общим родителем.

```css
.tabs { width: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0 auto; }
.tabs>input { display:none; }
.tabs>div { display: none;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
.tabs>label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 0 -5px -1px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #666666;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    background: #E0E0E0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs>input:checked + label {
    color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
#tab_1:checked ~ #txt_1,
#tab_2:checked ~ #txt_2,
#tab_3:checked ~ #txt_3,
#tab_4:checked ~ #txt_4 { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="inset" value="" id="tab_1" checked>
    <label for="tab_1">Вкладка №1</label>

    <input type="radio" name="inset" value="" id="tab_2">
    <label for="tab_2">Вкладка №2</label>

    <input type="radio" name="inset" value="" id="tab_3">
    <label for="tab_3">Вкладка №3</label>

    <input type="radio" name="inset" value="" id="tab_4">
    <label for="tab_4">Вкладка №4</label>

    <div id="txt_1">
        <p>Произвольное содержимое...</p>
        <p>Произвольное содержимое...</p>
        <p>Произвольное содержимое...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="txt_2">
        <p>Вторая вкладка</p>
    </div>
    <div id="txt_3">
        <p>Размеры содержимого вкладок</p>
        <p>могут отличаться по высоте!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="txt_4">
        <img src="image/logo.png" width="533" height="77" alt="Лого">
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.tabs { width: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0 auto; }
.tabs>.first>input { display:none; }
.tabs>.second>div { display: none;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
.tabs>.first>label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 0 -5px -1px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #666666;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    background: #E0E0E0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs>.first>input:checked + label {
    color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
#tab_1:checked ~ #txt_1,
#tab_2:checked ~ #txt_2,
#tab_3:checked ~ #txt_3,
#tab_4:checked ~ #txt_4 { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="first">
      <input type="radio" name="inset" value="" id="tab_1" checked>
      <label for="tab_1">Вкладка №1</label>

      <input type="radio" name="inset" value="" id="tab_2">
      <label for="tab_2">Вкладка №2</label>

      <input type="radio" name="inset" value="" id="tab_3">
      <label for="tab_3">Вкладка №3</label>

      <input type="radio" name="inset" value="" id="tab_4">
      <label for="tab_4">Вкладка №4</label>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
      <div id="txt_1">
          <p>Произвольное содержимое...</p>
          <p>Произвольное содержимое...</p>
          <p>Произвольное содержимое...</p>
      </div>
      <div id="txt_2">
          <p>Вторая вкладка</p>
      </div>
      <div id="txt_3">
          <p>Размеры содержимого вкладок</p>
          <p>могут отличаться по высоте!</p>
      </div>
      <div id="txt_4">
          <img src="image/logo.png" width="533" height="77" alt="Лого">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одним css'ом тут не обойтись - придётся использовать jQuery. В разметке нужно увязать инпут с вкладкой. Это можно сделать разными способами - я, например, в качестве value инпутов использовал id вкладок.

Далее в css нужно открыть первую вкладку по умолчанию (т.к. у нас первый инпут активен по умолчанию).

А дальше при клике на тот или иной инпут сопоставлять его с нужной вкладкой.

```js
$('input').click(function(){
  var link = $(this).val(); //получаем значение, связывающее инпут с вкладкой
  var tab = $('#'+link); //получаем нужную вкладку
  tab.css('display','block'); //открываем эту вкладку
  $('.second > div').not(tab).css('display','none'); //скрываем все другие вкладки
});
```

```css
.tabs { width: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0 auto; }
.tabs>.first>input { display:none; }
.tabs>.second>div {
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
.tabs>.second>div:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
.tabs>.first>label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 0 -5px -1px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #666666;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    background: #E0E0E0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs>.first>input:checked + label {
    color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="first">
      <input type="radio" name="inset" value="txt_1" id="tab_1" checked>
      <label for="tab_1">Вкладка №1</label>

      <input type="radio" name="inset" value="txt_2" id="tab_2">
      <label for="tab_2">Вкладка №2</label>

      <input type="radio" name="inset" value="txt_3" id="tab_3">
      <label for="tab_3">Вкладка №3</label>

      <input type="radio" name="inset" value="txt_4" id="tab_4">
      <label for="tab_4">Вкладка №4</label>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
      <div id="txt_1">
          <p>Произвольное содержимое...</p>
          <p>Произвольное содержимое...</p>
          <p>Произвольное содержимое...</p>
      </div>
      <div id="txt_2">
          <p>Вторая вкладка</p>
      </div>
      <div id="txt_3">
          <p>Размеры содержимого вкладок</p>
          <p>могут отличаться по высоте!</p>
      </div>
      <div id="txt_4">
          <img src="image/logo.png" width="533" height="77" alt="Лого">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```